# Ehcache Spring- custom key generator

Tags: java, spring, annotations, ehcache

I was working with [spring-ehcache-annotations](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/) and came across following scenario:

I have a simple POJO as follows

```
class Person{
 private Long id;
 private String name
 //some code
}
```

Now in DAO I have

```
public Person getPerson(Long personId){}

public Person UpdatePerson(Person person){}
```

Now in update person I need parameter of class Person and  I need to use personId of person as the key to cache.

This can be achieved by implmenenting [CacheKeyGenerator](http://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#7._How_can_I_generate_a_cache_key_that_isn%27t_based_on_the_a) for each class or putting blocks of if/else but can we have some configurable thing to give field of parameter to take as key ?

Comment: Can you switch to Spring 3.1 [cache abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)? Your use case is then easily achievable by `@Cacheable(key="#person.personId")` annotation

Comment: @Tomasz let me see it. thanks

Comment: @Tomasz It worked. I switched to Spring Cachable Abstraction

Comment: Glad I could help, I promoted my comment to an answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you switch to Spring 3.1 [cache abstraction](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)?

Your use case is then easily solvable by:

```
@Cacheable(key="#person.personId")
```

annotation.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be done with annotations.

If the `updatePerson` method takes a modified `Person` that you are persisting, then you need to annotate the update method with `TriggersRemove` to evict the updated Person from the cache.  Then you need to rerun the `getPerson` method to cache the updated Person.

See example code on the site: https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/source/browse/examples/ehcache-spring-example-1/trunk/src/main/java/com/googlecode/ehcache/annotations/examples/impl/SpringJdbcWeatherServiceImpl.java

Based on the `updateWeather` method in the link above, if I understand the issue at hand, you would do something like the following:

```
@Cacheable(cacheName="personCache", keyGenerator=@KeyGenerator(
                    name="ListCacheKeyGenerator",properties=@Property(name="includeMethod",value="false")))
public Weather getPerson(Long personId) {
    return (Person)(getSession().get(Person.class, personId));
}

@TriggersRemove(cacheName="personCache", keyGenerator=@KeyGenerator(
                    name="ListCacheKeyGenerator",properties=@Property(name="includeMethod",value="false")))
public Weather updatePerson(@PartialCacheKey Long personId, Person person) {
    getSession().merge(person);           
    return getPerson(personId);
 }
```

Comment: That's a bold statement; the code linked above is the official example code for the lib you are using.

Comment: The code you linked doesn't address to the solution of my problem.and I am deleting that comment since I think I misunderstood it. sorry for that. but your answer doesn't still answer my issue

Comment: or if you think it answers and I didn't get it please elaborate and comment back

Comment: This is the issue actually. that just to update a Pojo we need to pass two argument differently

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @PartialCacheKey to the personId parameter of getPerson method.

Just like this:

```
@Cacheable(cacheName="personCache", keyGenerator=@KeyGenerator(
                    name="ListCacheKeyGenerator",properties=@Property(name="includeMethod",value="false")))
public Weather getPerson(@PartialCacheKey Long personId) {
    return (Person)(getSession().get(Person.class, personId));
}

@TriggersRemove(cacheName="personCache", keyGenerator=@KeyGenerator(
                    name="ListCacheKeyGenerator",properties=@Property(name="includeMethod",value="false")))
public Weather updatePerson(@PartialCacheKey Long personId, Person person) {
    getSession().merge(person);           
    return getPerson(personId);
 }
```